# Passing in arguments to command line (PYTHON)

Tags: python, gdata

So I have a function from GDATA API (gdata.sample_util.authorize_client(client,      service=client.auth_service, source=client.source, scopes=client.auth_scopes)) which uses command line to receive arguments. How can I automate that so I can hard-code arguments?

Comment: What is your question, do you want to pass arguments from the command line? If so, what is your problem? What do you want to automate? Why and what do you want to hardcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean by hard-code arguments, arguments that you do not have to write everytime you call the function, or open the program from the command line? These are called Default Arguments. Check this out:

http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/defaultArgs.html

Example:

```
def ask_ok(prompt, retries=4, complaint='Yes or no, please!'):
    while 1:
        ok = raw_input(prompt)
        if ok in ('y', 'ye', 'yes'): return 1
        if ok in ('n', 'no', 'nop', 'nope'): return 0
        retries = retries - 1
        if retries < 0: raise IOError, 'refusenik user'
        print complaint
```

So you can actually call this function in different ways:

`ask_ok('Do you really want to quit?')`

or like this:

```
ask_ok('OK to overwrite the file?', 2)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if there were no command line arguments passed, you can just add parameters as you wish

```
import sys

sys.argv += ["-a"]
```